# How to show text in the status bar?

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

I want to show a number in the status bar, like all the battery apps do (when they show the percentage of the battery in the status bar, usually with a persistent notification).

It seems that I can't set a text to appear on the status bar, only an image.

So is the only way is to create X images (e.g. 100 images for battery apps each with a different name) and to switch between them?

Thanks.

Comment: Share the code how you are doing it . Then we may be able to help ??

Comment: there is no code, I'm looking for one. The standard notification code can be seen here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html . I just want to display text instead of an icon on the status bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use `setNumber()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setNumber%28int%29) with your `Notification.Builder` or `NotificationCompat.Builder`.

Comment: but that number appears on the notification. I want to show a number on the status bar, like in https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moddedlogic.android.BatteryStatus

Comment: @Ran: Well, that "number" *is* a `Notification`. You either go with 100 images or you use `setNumber()`.

Comment: I actually wanted to display a decimal number, so I would need infinite images. :) Thanks.

Comment: @Ran: Unfortunately, in most cases, these images have to be resources. I think the "large" image can be a `Bitmap`, which you could build on the fly, but that will only be used in some circumstances (e.g., Android 3.x tablets).